# add rows to list view android

Tags: android, listview, row

I have a listview with 30 rows with data parsed from internet.
When I have 30 rows, add a button, to Footer, which parses 30 new rows.
My problem is that I can not make the 30 new rows are added to those that already have the listview
I have to specify something to assign the adapter?
I've been looking for some time, but my code does not do it correctly.
I have tried many variations without success.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

thanks

Regards

Comment: what adapter do you use? if `arrayadapter`, simply add a collection of object to the adapter. `adapter.add(latest_update);`

Comment: Hi. I'm using an arraylist ... Read new rows perfectly but not added to the listview. replaces the old entries by new

list.getFirstVisiblePosition currentPosition = int ();
MinAdapter adapter = new (this, listaDeEntradas);
list.setAdapter (adapter);
list.setSelectionFromTop (currentPosition + 1, 0);

Comment: no, don't use new adapter. use something like `currentAdapter.add(newListItems);`

Comment: I understand.
I think my problem is that I have the "adadpter" in another class that extends BaseAdapter and would not know how to implement the "add"

I appreciate your attention

Comment: this may help you @MiguelC [arrayadapter](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.6_r2/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java)

Answer (score 0):

try notifiying the Listview by calling notifyDataSetChanged() on your adapter after new value addition, this will inturn notify your list view to refresh itself.

Hope this solves your issue.